# Generating random clusters' centers with max distance

Tags: cluster-analysis, k-means

I have a sequential data (one instance per time) to be clustered into two classes. I want to use the sequential version of K-means (sequential K-means) for this task.

Upon randomly specifying the centers of the two clusters for the algorithm at the beginning, I want for the distance between them to be as max as possible (i.e., very away from each other) so the distribution of the the resulting two clusters will not be affected by the initial centers.

**Is my thinking correct? if so, how can I do that?**

Comment: Maybe you can give more details about your data and what it is you want to achieve, because I don't think I fully understand. K-Means will try to divide your data into equally sized clusters and assumes that the mean value will converge to the center of the cluster. Maybe another algorithm would be more appropriate?

Comment: I made some changes to the question, hope it's clear now

Answer (score 0):

Rather try to best estimate the true means. That is the optimum steategy.

If you just want to make them far apart, that can lead to badly assigned points inbetween.